# libvirt Domain Xml questions

Tags: xml, config, kvm, libvirt

In a typical libvirt Domain Xml sample as follows:

`<domain type='qemu'><memory>219136</memory><currentMemory>219136</currentMemory><vcpu>1</vcpu><on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff><on_reboot>restart</on_reboot><on_crash>destroy</on_crash></domain>`

There're two pairs of tags inisde, one is < currentMemory >< /currentMemory > and the other is < memory >< /memory >

What's the difference of these?

Answer (score 1):

"memory" tag shows the maximum memory allocation for the guest at the boot time
while, "currentMemory" tag shows actual allocation of memory for the guest.

You may want to read about specifying memory allocation in Libvirt domain XML: http://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsMemoryAllocation